# "Enact Change" - Is it correct?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, grammaticality, style-manuals

- "How to enact change in..."
- "We enacted change by..."

I've seen this used in quite a few contexts, but it doesn't seem to make much sense when I look at the word "enact" in the dictionary.

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enact):

> Definition of enact
>
> **1**: to establish by legal and authoritative act
>   specifically : to make into law
>   enact a bill
>
> **2**: ACT OUT enact a role

Looking at an [n-gram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=enact%20change&year_start=1900&year_end=2003&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cenact%20change%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cenact%20change%3B%2Cc0), its use is non-zero and growing, but nowhere near the usage of the phrase "effect change".
[image: ngram of the term "enact change"]

Typically when I've seen it used, it indicates that a someone is *effecting* a change, but from a dictionary sense, does the phrase "enact change" make sense? My thought is no, but I'm looking for a reality check on it to make sure I'm not misinterpreting the dictionary entries.

Comment: It makes sense.  Read the first definition again, only not so literally.

Comment: I guess you're right, I was reading it too literally in the legal sense of it. Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/enact) (and, I'd guess, OED) is the best here:

> **enact** ...
>
> 1. (transitive, law) to make (a bill) into law
> 2. (transitive) to act the part of; to play
> 3. (transitive) to do; to effect

though it's even more highfalutin' than *effect*. I'd use 'bring about'. [These Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bring+about+change%2Ceffect+change%2Cenact+change&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbring%20about%20change%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ceffect%20change%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cenact%20change%3B%2Cc0) would indicate that 'effect change' surprisingly (to me) rivals 'bring about change' in writing, while 'enact change' is rarefied.

Answer (score -2):

Change is a verb. Making it a noun and adding another verb to it is an abomination, regardless of whether or not the verb is appropriate. I would advise:

> Change things

Why is it an abomination? Because the purpose of language is to communicate ideas clearly. Unless, of course, you are writing poetry; but I doubt that this is poetry.